# The following theorem proving and wanted

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove:

Graph of any equation for one or two unknowns X,Y is a straight line and vice versa.

$$ Ax+By+C=0 $$

Comment: Graph depends on the degree Of equation can you more clearly ask the question

Comment: It is not true. If $A=B=C=0$ then it is the whole space, and if $A=B=0$ and $C\neq0$ then it is the empty set. Btw, what exactly is a straight line? If a formal definition lacks then a formal proof will lack as well.

Comment: Supposing that $B \neq 0$ or $A \neq 0 $, I gave you a full proof of why this is a straight line equation. First of all, take a good look at it and realize that it cannot be proved if you do not take that $B \neq 0$ or $A \neq 0 $. Secondly, if it fits your question please make sure to approve the answer so that the question goes down as answered.

Comment: @justin77 drhab's point is a good one. It is impossible to answer this unless you tell us your definition of a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to suppose that either $B \neq 0$ or $A \neq 0 $, otherwise you cannot make a case.

If $B \neq 0 $ then your equation is written as : $ y = - \frac{A}{B} x - \frac{C}{B} $ which is an equation of a line with $λ = - \frac{A}{B}$ and this line intersects with $yy'$ at the point : $(0, -\frac{C}{B})$.

If $B=0$ then, $A\neq0$ and the equation is written as : $x= - \frac{C}{A} $ which is the equation of a lien that is perpendicular to $x'x$, at the point $(- \frac{C}{A}, 0) $.

Then, we proved that the equation $Ax + By + C = 0$ with $B \neq 0$ or $A \neq 0 $, represents a line.

Please keep in mind that this is an equation that describes a line in the $2$-Dimension ($\mathbb R^2$) plane. The equation of a line in $\mathbb R^3$ is different.

Comment: So what is your definition of a straight line? All you have done is state that various equations represent straight lines.